# Passing string to a function when unsigned int expected in C

Tags: c, string, unsigned-integer

In the main I call this function:

```
expects_unsigned_int("some text");
```

Defined like this:

```
expects_unsigned_int(unsigned int val)
```

I would like to print the string passed inside the function. Is it possible to do it in the way `expects_unsigned_int()` is defined?

This is what I tried:

```
expects_unsigned_int(unsigned int val) {
    unsigned int* string = 0;
    string = (unsigned int*) val;
    printf("%s", (char*)string);
}
```

But it doesn't print anything.

Comment: *Why* are you trying to do this? A string literal is not a `unsigned int`, this is absolutely unsafe

Comment: Although totally not recommended, it works for me (although your version is way too complicated, even `printf("%s", (char*)val);` would probably work. The question is mainly, why do you want to do this? Aren't we looking at an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here?

Comment: it compiles with warnings and prints "some text"

Comment: You've probably just discovered that pointers and ints happen to be the same size on your platform. That's not guaranteed, and this code is anyway _awful_. Why on earth would you want to depend on this fragile, non-portable behaviour?

Comment: maybe he lacks some assembler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole point of a *type* in a language like C is that it describes some well-defined, useful set of values.

A value of type `unsigned int` can hold any integer in a range defined by your compiler and processor.  This is typically a 32-bit integer, meaning that an `unsigned int` can hold any integer from 0 to 4294967295.  But an `unsigned int` can not hold the value 5000000000 (it's too big), or the value 123.456 (it's not an integer) or the value "hello, world" (strings aren't integers).

A value of type `char *` can hold a pointer to a character anywhere in the usable address space on your computer.  So it can hold a pointer to a single character, or it can hold a pointer to a null-terminated array of characters like "hello, world", or it can hold a NULL pointer.  But it is not intended to hold an integer, or a floating-point value.

Sometimes, under constrained or unusual circumstances, programmers try to bend the rules, by wedging a value of one type into a variable of a different type.  Sometimes you can make this work, sometimes you can't.  It's almost always a significantly bad idea.  Even if it can be made to work, it's often the case that it works properly on one machine, but not others.

Let's look more carefully at what you're doing.  (I'm filling in a few details you left out.)

```
void expects_unsigned_int(unsigned int);
```

Here we tell the compiler that there's going to be a function named `expects_unsigned_int` that accepts one argument of type `unsigned int` and returns nothing.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    expects_unsigned_int("some text");
}
```

Here we call that function, passing an argument of type `char *`.  We're in trouble already, of course.  You can't wedge a `char *` into an `unsigned int` sized slot.  A proper compiler will give you a serious warning, if not an outright error, here.  Mine says

```
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘expects_unsigned_int’ makes integer from pointer without a cast
expected ‘unsigned int’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
```

These warnings make sense, and are consistent with my explanations so far of what we should and shouldn't do with types.

As you may know, a pointer is "just" an address, and on most machines an address is "just" a bit pattern of some size, so you can convince yourself that it ought to be possible to jam a pointer into an integer.  The key question, which we'll return to in a minute, is whether type `unsigned int` is literally big enough to hold all possible values of type `char *`.

```
void expects_unsigned_int(unsigned int val) {
```

Here we begin defining the details of function `expects_unsigned_int`.  Again we say that it accepts one argument of type `unsigned int` and returns nothing.  That's consistent with the earlier prototype declaration.  All right so far.

```
unsigned int* string = 0;
```

Here we declare a pointer of type `unsigned int *` and initialize it to the null pointer.  We don't really need this intermediate pointer, and in this case it doesn't matter whether we initialize it, since we're about to overwrite it.

```
string = (unsigned int*) val;
```

Here's where the trouble begins.  We have an unsigned int value, and we attempt to convert it into a pointer.  Again, this might seem reasonable, since pointers are "just" addresses and addresses are "just" bit patterns.

The other thing we have is an explicit cast.  In this case, surprisingly, the cast is not really "doing" the conversion from `unsigned int` to `unsigned int *`.  If we wrote the assignment without the cast, like this:

```
string = val;
```

the compiler would see an `unsigned int` value on the right-hand side, and a pointer of type `unsigned int *` on the left-hand side, and it would attempt to perform the same conversion implicitly.  But since it's a dangerous and potentially meaningless conversion, the compiler would warn about it.  Mine says

```
warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

But when you write an explicit cast, for most compilers what this means is, "trust me, I know what I'm doing, do this conversion and keep your doubts to yourself, I don't want to hear any of your warnings."

Finally,

```
printf("%s", (char*)string);
```

Here we do two things.  First we explicitly convert the `unsigned int *` pointer into a `char *` pointer.  That's also a questionable conversion, but of a much lesser concern.  On the vast majority of computers today, all pointers (no matter what they point to) have the same size and representation, so a conversion like this is most unlikely to cause any problems.

And then the second thing we do is, finally, try to print the `char *` pointer using `printf` and `%s`.  As you've discovered, it doesn't always work.  It doesn't work for me on my computer, either.

There are computers where it would work, so the answer to your question "Is it possible to do it?" is "Yes, maybe, but."

Why didn't it work for you?  I can't be sure, but it's probably for the same reason it didn't work for me.  On my machine, pointers are 64 bits, but regular ints (including `unsigned int) are 32 bits.  So when we called

```
expects_unsigned_int("some text");
```

and attempted to wedge a pointer into an int-sized slot, we scraped off 32 of its 64 bits.  That's an information-losing transformation, so it's very likely to be an unrecoverable error.

Let's print some additional information, so we can confirm that this is what's going on.  I encourage you to make these modifications to your program on your computer, so you can see what results you get.

Let's rewrite `main` like this:

```
int main()
{
    char *string = "some text";
    printf("string = %p = %s\n", string, string);
    printf("int: %d, pointer: %d\n", (int)sizeof(unsigned int), (int)sizeof(string));
    expects_unsigned_int(string);
}
```

We're using the `printf` format `%p` to print the pointer.  This will show us a representation of the bit pattern that makes up the pointer value (however big it is), typically in hexadecimal.  We're also using `sizeof()` to tell us how big ints and pointers are on the machine we're using.

Let's rewrite `expects_unsigned_int` like this:

```
void expects_unsigned_int(unsigned int val) {
    char *string = val;
    printf("val = %x\n", val);
    printf("string = %p\n", string);
    printf("string = %s\n", string);
}
```

Here we're printing both the value of `val` as it comes in, and the pointer we recover from it (again, using `%p`).  Also, I'm making `string` of type `char *`, since there was no point in having it `unsigned int *`.

When I run the modified program, here's what I get:

```
string = 0x101295f20 = some text
int: 4, pointer: 8
val = 1295f20
string = 0x1295f20
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Immediately we see several things:

- Pointers are bigger than ints on this machine (as I was saying earlier).  There's no way we're going to be able to stuff a pointer into an int without potentially losing data.
- We're indeed scraping off some of the bits of the sting pointer.  It starts out being `101295f20` and ends up as `1295f20`.
- The program doesn't work.  It crashes with a segmentation violation, likely because the mangled pointer value `0x1295f20` points outside its address space.

So how do we fix this?  The best way would be to *not* try to pass a pointer value through a slot that's designed to hold integers.

Or, if we really wanted to, if we were bound and determined to convert pointers to integers and back again, we could try using a bigger integer, such as an `unsigned long int`.  (And if that wasn't big enough, we could also try `unsigned long long int`.)

I rewrote `main` like this:

```
void expects_unsigned_long_int(unsigned long int val);

int main()
{
    char *string = "some text";
    printf("string = %p = %s\n", string, string);
        printf("int: %d, pointer: %d\n", (int)sizeof(unsigned long int), (int)sizeof(string));
    expects_unsigned_long_int(string);
}
```

And then `expects_unsigned_long_int` looks like this:

```
void expects_unsigned_long_int(unsigned long int val) {
    char *string = val;
    printf("val = %x\n", val);
    printf("string = %p\n", string);
    printf("string = %s\n", string);
}
```

I still get warnings when I compile it, but now when I run it it prints

```
string = 0x10a09df20 = some text
int: 8, pointer: 8
val = a09df20
string = 0x10a09df20
string = some text
```

So it looks like type `unsigned long int` is big enough (for now), and no bits get scraped off, and the original pointer value is successfully recovered inside `expects_unsigned_long_int`, and the string prints correctly.

But, in closing, please, figure out a better way of doing this!

---

Addendum: I said, with some uncertainty, that we could try `unsigned long int`, or maybe `unsigned long long int`.  If you want more certainty, it turns out that there is a special integer type that's supposed to be the right size for jamming a pointer into it: `uintptr_t`, as defined in `<stdint.h>`.  So, if you're "bound and determined to convert pointers to integers", that's the right type to use, although you have to beware that it's an optional type, since there can theoretically be an exotic machine out there somewhere that does support C but whose pointers are bigger than any of its integer types.

Comment: Thank you for your nice explanation, it helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

The string when given as argument decays to the address of its first element, which is then converted to an `unsigned int`. If that integer is large enough to hold the address without losing bits, you could convert it back:

```
char* pointer1 = "abcde";
unsigned int integer = pointer1;
char* pointer2 = integer;
if (pointer1 == pointer2) {
    printf("Works, kindof.\n");
}
```

However, as others pointed out in the comments, the very approach is bad and you shouldn't use this to solve whatever problem you have. Instead, first read about the meaning of an "XY problem" and then ask another question that addresses the actual problem here.